# Intercepting HTML pages and rendering JSON

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, controllers

Is there any way for me to run Javascript in a Rails controller? I basically have a Javascript widget that I am loading in the browser right now (the script is hosted somewhere else).

I want to run it server-side, and then parse it's output (renders HTML) and return it via an API call. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are talking about is a `_partial_name_here.js.erb` template. You can render it like any partial from the controller, and you can write your JS there. More details [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).